# Распознавание лиц Xamarin

Tags: android, c#, .net, xamarin, mono

Пишу академическое приложение по распознаванию лиц для Андроид (Xamarin). Был небольшой опыт с WPF и Emguu для десктопа, очень интересна данная тема. Написал программу для андроид на Xamarin(изучаю framework всего несколько дней), получилось распознавать лица с готовой фотографии при помощи Android API (FaceDetector и Bitmap). Топчусь на месте, так как не знаю, нужно ли дальше двигаться в сторону Android API. Хочу теперь попробовать сделать захват лица в реальном времени со стрима камеры и обвести лицо в рамку и посчитать расстояние от камеры до лица(по фото получилось, у FaceDetector есть свойство eyeDistance). Посоветуйте пожалуйста, как это можно сделать на C# и Xamarin?

Comment: Как сделать на Xamarin не знаю, а для C# есть отличная библиотека Aforge.Net

Comment: Я просто написал уже приложение на Android Api... Хотелось бы с ним реализовать. Но не могу найти нормальный пример или туториал. За наводку спасибо!

Comment: у DLIB прекрасные функции работы с лицом - dlib.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В DLIB прекрасные функции работы с лицом - dlib.net
В последней версии OpenCV тоже появились функции выделения ландшафта лица, но я их не пробовал пока. А стандартные детекторы HAAR и LBP в OpenCV хуже чем у DLIB.
Качество детектора DLIB точно выше чем в Android API, но про Xamarin тогда придется забыть - обертки C# для DLIB нет. 
Для OpenCV есть несколько оберток - EmguCV, OpenCV for Unity.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. С EmguCV знаком не по наслышке. Пилил на нем курсовик на WPF. Сейчас работаю с андроид. Вот и пришлось использовать Android Api и прикрутил еще к нему Microsoft Oxford. Пока проект не актуален, немного забросил.